# How to feed high resolution images to the model?

Tags: deep-learning, object-detection, image-preprocessing, image

I want to do object detection , normally we have a size of image `256 x 256` or `128 x 128` but what if we want to feed high resolution images to the model like `8000 x 6000` then How it could be done ?

Answer (score 1):

The main idea is to use `image pyramids` in these situations to decompose an image into a set of spatial component images e.g., object detection with high-resolution images. If you are more interested in this topic, you can read this article: [Object detection algorithm for high-resolution images based on convolutional neural network and multiscale processing](http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-2864/paper12.pdf)

There is a good blog that explains well how to use pyramids in neural networks:
[FPN — Feature Pyramid Network (Object Detection)](https://towardsdatascience.com/review-fpn-feature-pyramid-network-object-detection-262fc7482610)
[image: image taken from the first reference]